# Bitlocker GPO on Tablet/Surface/Slate - Require additional authentication at startup - Enabled, but not offering option to set PIN

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, bitlocker

I'm setting up a Surface Pro 5 - m3, Windows 10. I have enabled several options for Bitlocker via GPO, one of which is `Require additional authentication at startup`, so that the user must enter a PIN before windows will load.

Using `rsop.msc`, I can see that the relevant GPO is enabled ...

[image]

However, when i come to activate/manage bitlocker, there is no option to set a PIN, just to use a USB flash drive, or have it unlocked automatically ...

[image]

This same policy has worked fine on the last 5+ Dell Optiplex and Inspiron desktops that I have set up, but I cannot figure out what the problem is with this tablet?! Thanks!

Just want to add that the tpm console says the tpm has a status of 'ready'.

---

Also, device manager shows that that TPM is version 2.0, and is working correctly ...

[image]

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Thanks for your reply. Those options weren't enabled because I hadn't included them in my GPO (I wasn't fussed about minimum length, and I wasn't intending on using enhanced PINs). I enabled them both just to see if it made a difference, but unfortunately it didn't! Thanks for your help though :0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was remarkably simple. You need to enable `Enable use of BitLocker Authentication requiring preboot keyboard input on slates`.

In short, some tablets don't provision a pre-boot on-screen keyboard, and thus would have no means to enter a PIN before boot.

After enabling this setting in my GPO, the required "Enter a PIN" option appeared as expected when I enabled Bitlocker on the OS drive.

Further reading [Bitlocker PIN on Surface Pro 3 and Other Tablets](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/07/13/bitlocker-pin-on-surface-pro-3-and-other-tablets/)